# Why is my TableView returning Nil in VIPER?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am learning VIPER. I have successfully processed the data from `View->Presnter->Interactor` and returning the data from `Interactor->Presenter->View`. The data is successfully coming back to me and in that `extension` I am trying to reload the data.

When I try to reload the data, the `TableView` comes nil. Why is it nil? When I use MVC pattern I do not see the `TableView` coming nil and everything works fine. Any clue?

Here is my `TableView`

`@IBOutlet  weak var matchTable: UITableView!`

It is connected to the `File Owner`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setup()
    matchTable.delegate = self
    matchTable.dataSource = self
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    presentor?.initiateFetch()
}
```

And here is the `extension` to `ViewController`.

```
extension MatchListingViewController: PresenterToViewProtocol{

    func showMatches(match: MatchDetails?, banner: Banner?) {
        matchD = match
        bannerD = banner
        matchTable.reloadData()
    }

    func showError() {
        print("I am there")
    }
}
```

Here when the function `showMatches` is called I get the data but when I reload it throws an error that `matchTable` is nil. Any help?

Comment: Are you calling `showMatches` method after `viewDidLoad` called?

Comment: It is in `extension`. So, I don't know it is calling after or before. I know that it is called via the `presentor?.initiateFetch()`.

Comment: Can you make sure that by adding print statement on `showMatches` and `viewDidLoad` methods and confirm which one calls first?

Comment: Sure man, one sec.

Comment: @Natarajan `viewDidLoad` called first.

Comment: How are you linking presenter to vc ?

Comment: "Why is my TableView returning Nil in VIPER?" Because VIPER. VIPER in iOS takes the simple and resourceful and makes it unnecessarily complex and bloated.

Comment: @CZ54 I am linking via `PresenterToViewProtocol`

Comment: @narddog Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot injection presentor or init protocol. The nil isn't come from tableView, need more code to know exactly which is wrong here.

in VC class:

```
extension MatchListingViewController: PresenterToViewProtocol


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.presentor?.initProtocol(self)
}
```

in presentor class:

```
func initProtocol(_ protocol: PresenterToViewProtocol) {
        self.protocol = protocol
        self.initiateFetch()
    }
```

then

```
self.protocol?.showMatches(match: match, banner: banner)
```

Comment: Didn't get it I am not using anything for injection. I am calling from `View to Presentor to Interactor and then back`. I followed this tutorial exactly. https://medium.com/cr8resume/viper-architecture-for-ios-project-with-simple-demo-example-7a07321dbd29

Comment: Why are you calling viewWillAppear in extension?

Comment: i amn't calling viewWillAppear in extension, i said in MatchListingViewController , must to add PresenterToViewProtocol, and in viewWillAppear initProtocol. :D

Comment: I have read your medium link, did you followed exactly to NoticeRouter ?

Comment: Yes and No. I followed it first and didn't saw any difference. You can see that in their `NoticePresenter` they have written `PresenterToRouterProtocol?`, but I have to call the class otherwise it goes nil. So, when this tableview error came along I removed the `createModule` in `Router` and didn't saw any change.